# text inside space like messenger in jlist or jtextarea java

Tags: java, eclipse, netbeans, jtextarea, jlist

Hey i need to help i would to do something like inside that image ?
 if can anyone help me , thank you before help me

[image]

Comment: At lot will depend on how you're achieving the results. You could layout constraints or EmptyBorders

Comment: See documentation for JTextPane

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22346858/bottom-to-top-layout-in-java-with-dynamic-sizing).